# MJML run and watch error

Tags: mjml

I'm following the tutorial on https://mjml.io/documentation/#basic-layout-example
And followed these instructions to install https://mjml.io/download

But whenever I want to use **./node_modules/.bin/mjml index.mjml** or **mjml index.mjml** I get the following error:
    Command 'sed' is available in '/bin/sed'
    The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the 
    PATH environment variable.
    sed: command not found
    /usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and Google hasn't been helpful so far. 
Any idea why this is happening? Thanks for your time :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have messed your PATH environment variable. The sed program is there as is part of the core packages. You can try to do something like the mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452488/the-command-could-not-be-located-because-usr-bin-is-not-included-in-the-path).

Also try to reach the mjml support group in [slack](http://mjml.slack.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not installed node properly. Try reinstalling it.
If you reinstalled the node and then also you are facing the problem then there is some problem with Windows because a few days ago I was facing a problem when I was running the **npm run build** command then I switch to my Virtual box Linux OS there it works fabulously.

Comment: Please refrain from asking a question as part of the answer. Please do go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer